# install lxml error, no such file or directory: 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c'

Tags: python, macos

error found when I install xml
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c'
but there are no file 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c' in xml project

```
Building lxml version 3.6.0.
Building with Cython 0.24.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /opt/local/lib
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to src/lxml.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/lxml.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/lxml.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/lxml.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree.c' under directory 'src/lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.objectify.c' under directory 'src/lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree.h' under directory 'src/lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree_api.h' under directory 'src/lxml'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'doc'
writing manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c'
clang: error: no input files
Compile failed: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
cc -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitMewYkg.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitMewYkg.o
/tmp/xmlXPathInitMewYkg.c:2:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main (int argc, char **argv) {
^~~~
1 warning generated.
cc tmp/xmlXPathInitMewYkg.o -L/opt/local/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

what can i do ,

thanks